# php)post and save it in json

Tags: php, json, post

problem:php)post and save it in json
I want to put a value in json with a post, but I don't know how to do it.

I want to add the value "id" to the post and put it in json.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Use php json_decode() json_encode() functions. if your data is already in json format, decode it first, than add your value in it, than encode it again.